# Why doesn't this method work for scaling a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling

Hello I am relatively new to python and having trouble understanding the error messages I am getting.

I am working on the PIMA india diabetes dataset, and I have a subset of the predictors as a training data
The subset is a pandas data frame of shape(615,8) called train_pred. Each column is a strictly numeric value (Pregnancies, Glucose,.. etc).

I wanted to scale and centre each row, that is for each entry, subtract mean and divide by the standard deviation.

I tried defining a function to do this,

```
def myScale(dat):
    for i in range(len(dat.columns)):
        getMean=dat.iloc[:,i].mean()
        getSd=np.sqrt(dat.iloc[:,i].var())
        dat.iloc[:,i]=(dat.iloc[:,i]-getMean)/(getSd)
```

But when I try to run this function for example as

`train_pred.apply(scale,axis='0')`
or `train_pred.apply(scale)` or even `train_pred.apply(lambda(z):scale(z))`
I get
AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'", 'occurred at index Pregnancies')

However, if I do it without a function and set dat=train_pred, and run the above, it works as intended. I am frustrated and not sure what this error is or why it is occurring. So for example, it would work in the case since I am only dealing with the one dataset, but it wont work if I wanted to apply the scale function on a dataset of another form. I don't understand the error either. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: did you pass the train_pred as an argument for the function

Comment: Thanks, that works for calling it on the data frame, but I am still wondering why I couldn't use the apply method